# A simple picture for the fluctuation-dissipation theorem?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

In condensed matter and materials physics it is often assumed that the response of a condensed phase to some perturbation is determined by the fluctuations of the system at equilibrium (without perturbations). For example, the electric resistance of a liquid (the response of the current to an applied field) is determined by the mean squared displacement of the charge carriers (the fluctuations) at equilibrium.

Pictorially, this makes sense because if the charge carriers move slowly at equilibrium it will be probably not be easy to make them move, so for small fluctuations the current response would probably be small. Another way to say this, the difference between motion at equilibrium (without field) and motion out of equilibrium (with applied field) is that there is a small bias in the direction of the field, but the motion is otherwise essentially the same.

Formally, this relation is proven by the fluctuation-dissipation theorem for a statistical mechanical (micro-canonical or canonical) system subject to small perturbation (small term added to Hamiltonian).

My concern is that I think that the validity of this FDT relation can be formulated for systems more general than statistical mechanical (micro-canonical and canonical) systems. Pictorially, I think whenever the system can be described as a stochastic variable fluctuating in some potential landscape between some potential minima, then the response should always be related to the barrier heights of those minima, which also determine the magnitude of the fluctuations at equilibrium (without bias).

So is it possible to derive FDT also for this setting ?